# JUnit test inheritance doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, junit, surefire

```
public abstract class GenericTests<T extends Number> {
  protected abstract T getT();      

  @Test public void test1() {
    getT();
  }
}

public class ConcreteTests1 extends GenericTests<Integer> { ... }
public class ConcreteTests2 extends GenericTests<Double> { ... }
```

No tests are executed at all, both concrete classes are ignored. How do I make it work? (I expect `test1()` to be executed for both `Integer` and `Double`).

I use JUnit 4.8.1.

**Update**: it appeared that problem is related with maven-surefire-plugin and not JUnit itself. See my answer below.

Comment: Do you need to extend TestCase?

Comment: Is it required even in case I use annotations?

Comment: Junit4 doesn't require you to extend TestCase but how are you running these?  From the command line?  From Eclipse?

Comment: @jeff: `mvn clean test`. That works fine for other tests in the same package, the only difference is, these tests doesn't use inheritance.

Comment: Can you include the content of one of the subclasses

Comment: What is B? surely it should be Number unless you sub-classed a class with 2 classes with the same name, Double and Integer, as a classes in the core library?

Comment: @whatsthebeef: it DOESN'T matter :-)

Comment: I would have thought with your rep you have been exposed to the level of pedantry required on this site, obviously not.

Comment: @whatsthebee: Sorry, I see what you mean now. Yes, I should have used `Number` instead of `B`. It's pretty minor detail, but yes, it should be more pedantic. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Renamed all my classes to have suffix "Test" and now it works (`Concrete1Test`, `Concrete2Test`).

**Update**:

That's related with default settings of maven-surefire-plugin.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> `**/Test*.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "Test".
> `**/*Test.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "Test".
> `**/*TestCase.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "TestCase".

Comment: This is because the surefire-plugin maven uses to run tests "discovers" tests based on class names. They have to match one of a few accepted patterns, BlahTest being one of them. Here is more information on the default settings and how you can customize them in your config... http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: Yep, this makes sense. The default file names used by the surefire plugin (the maven plugin that executes when you call `mvn test`) are `**/Test*.java`, `**/*Test.java` and `**/*TestCase.java`. Ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Eclipse, using your skeleton code, and it worked fine:

Base Class:

```
package stkoverflow;

import org.junit.Test;

public abstract class GenericTests<T> {
    protected abstract T getT();

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        getT();
    }    
}
```

Subclass:

```
package stkoverflow;

public class ConcreteTests1 extends GenericTests<Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer getT() {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Running ConcreteTests1 in Eclipse Junit Runner worked fine.  Perhaps the issue is with Maven?